# SQL update table via join?

Tags: sql, view

I have the following database and wish to update the `room` table. The table `room` lists a room type that is either single, double or king, the price is the price of each room per night and the name in Hotel is the name of the hotel.

What I need to do is change all double rooms to king rooms which are in the Scotty Hotel and also increase their price by 10%.

I know how to update the price and the type when it is in a single table, but it seems here I need to join hotel and room on HNO and thus update. Nested query maybe?

```
create table Hotel  (
   HNo char(4),
   Name varchar(20)   not null,
   Address varchar(50),
   Constraint PK_Hotel Primary Key (HNo)
);

create table Room  (
   RNo char(4),
   HNo char(4),
   Type char(6) not null,
   Price decimal (7,2),
   Constraint PK_Room Primary Key (HNo, RNo),
   Constraint FK_Room Foreign Key (HNo)
   references Hotel (HNo)
);


create table Guest  (
   GNo char(4),
   Name varchar(20) not null,
   Address varchar(50),
   Constraint PK_Guest Primary Key (GNo)

);

create table Booking   (
   HNo char(4),
   GNo char(4),
   DateFrom date,
   DateTo date,
   RNo char(4),
   Constraint PK_Booking Primary Key (HNo, GNo, DateFrom),
   Constraint FK_Booking Foreign Key (GNo)
   references Guest (GNo),
   Constraint FK_Booking_room Foreign Key (HNo, RNo)
   references Room (HNo, RNo),
   Constraint FK_Booking_hotel Foreign Key (HNo)
   references Hotel (HNo)
);
```

I have two main questions:

1. Is it possible to do an update to a table, that requires a join?
2. I want to list guests via a view. Can I create a view which contains the hotel name and number of distinct guests that have ever stayed in the hotel?

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: You have multiple errors in your code above, such that I can't quickly build a SQL Fiddle to help you with this.  Eg an additional closing parenthesis `)` at the end of `create table Hotel`

Comment: @Sepster What errors do you see? Apart from the missing `;`, which are not required in some DBMS, I don't see anything.

Comment: @ypercube I didn't initially debug beyond the first problem I encountered, but yes it turned out that it was only missing `;`.  I must admit I assumed mySql. Have edited code to reflect - I added `;` as I believe that while they're not universally required, they are pretty much universally accepted? (Please re-edit if that's not the case).

Answer (score 11):

First, it is a good idea to do a select to ensure your search/filter criteria are correct:

```
SELECT
  h.Name,
  r.RNo,
  r.Type,
  r.Price

FROM
  room r

  INNER JOIN hotel h
  on h.hno = r.hno

WHERE
  h.name = 'Scotty Hotel'
  and
  r.type = 'Double' ;
```

If this targets the correct rows, then have at 'em with an update query *using the same filter criteria*, as follows.

Hint, it pays to copy your entire `SELECT` query and then edit it to form your new `UPDATE` query.  eg for mySql, replace `FROM` with `UPDATE` (and leave the contents of the original `FROM` clause to form your new `UPDATE` clause), leave the `WHERE` in place, and use the contents of your `SELECT` list from the original query as the basis on which to form your new `SET` clause (immediately prior to your `WHERE` clause).

This code is for **mySql**:

```
UPDATE room r 

  INNER JOIN hotel h
  on h.hno = r.hno

SET
  r.type = 'King',
  r.price = r.price * 1.1

WHERE
  h.name = 'Scotty Hotel'
  and
  r.type = 'Double' ;
```

This code is for **MS SQL Server**:

```
UPDATE r

SET
  r.type = 'King',
  r.price = r.price * 1.1

FROM
  room r

  INNER JOIN hotel h
  on h.hno = r.hno

WHERE
  h.name = 'Scotty Hotel'
  and
  r.type = 'Double' ;
```

Comment: +1 from me. Just note that this syntax for update `UPDATE a JOIN b SET ...` will work in MySQL only.

Comment: @ypercube Good point, thanks.  I've added an MSSQL version, I'd appreciate your peer review/edit?

Comment: @ypercube I was _looking_ for a way to reference the table alias in the `UPDATE` clause, but the example I looked at on MSDN used the full name there even when using an alias in the `FROM`.  Thanks for clearing that up for me.

Comment: I think it would also work as you had it but I find it clearer this way. (also added the `;` :)

Answer (score 2):

Why does not this work?

```
UPDATE ROOM A SET TYPE='King', A.PRICE=A.PRICE*1.1 
WHERE A.TYPE ='DOUBLE' AND 
A.HNO IN (SELECT HNO FROM HOTEL WHERE NAME='Scotty')
```

Hope that this works.
This assumes that the hotel name Scotty is unique, of course

Comment: HNO sorry is actually the ID number of the hotel, and not characters 'scotty'. So my assumption is that you would have to join the tables to place 'Scotty Hotel' for hotel name?